# ISO to MKV batch conversion for dummies

Tags: iso, conversion, mint, mkv, plex

I've tried finding a solution to my problem - unfortunately without luck.
I've just installed Plex Media Server and are loving in! However, it can't play the 100 ISO-files with my DVD-movies that I ripped years ago. Is there any way to convert these ISO's to MKV in a batch - including the multiple languages and subtitles? I just want a 1:1 conversion of each ISO.

I doesn't matter if it's going to be in Windows or Linux. I got both - but I'll need a step-by-step guide if it's going to be in Linux.
I tried VidCoder for Windows, but unfortunately it won't transfer more than one language and no subtitles at all when batch-converting. :-/

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you mount the .iso file, and then open that as if it were an actual dvd disk? Would your player/server see it as a dvd video disk & play it?

I haven't tried recently, but I think I remember the options...

```
 mount -o loop file.iso /mnt/point
```

See the man pages for `mount` & `losetup` for more info.

Would be convenient to have some way to "click to mount" each .iso file, I'm not familiar with Plex but I think it's pretty flexible... Maybe a script or an action or something?

Comment: That could be a solution. On the other hand, I'd hate to have to mount all 100 ISO's at all times. The point for having a Plex Server - for me - is to be able to stream whatever movie or whatever song I'd like to see/hear at any given moment and in a quality that the internet connection can substain. That's why I'm going with a dedicated Plex Server solution instead of just using my NAS. My NAS does not support transcoding - but that's off topic :-)

Comment: I'd like to:
- Stream ISO's to whatever device I'm using to access my server in whatever quality I need. For that I need transcoding - and for that I need a format that Plex Media Server will support.

Therefor, I'd like to:
- Convert all my ISO's into MKV's keeping both audio-tracks, subtitles and original quality (or as close to as I can come) since Plex Media Server will handle the transcoding on-the-fly.

Comment: Maybe check on the Plex forums, I'm sure you're not the first person who wants to watch ISO files. I think they're at https://forums.plex.tv/ right? At least with a "Roku" it should work... http://www.lehsys.com/2012/06/roku-with-plex-playing-isos-very-cool/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe HandBrake will work here? It can read ISOs, and will convert to MKV with audio and subs - and also has a batch mode.

Answer (score 0):

Both MakeMKV and ByteCopy work on Windows. I don't have a review on both but both are easy to use, you may google for the instructions. Handbrake is mainly designed for converting digital media files, it will not convert protected discs though. So Handbrake may not work well if your ISI's are still under commercial protection.